# Saving data to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cytoscape.js

How to save data generated by forEach in an array with the formation: `('label') + ';' + pr.rank (n)`, where `pr.rank(n)` is the calculated value?

I'm using the Cytoscape.js library.

```
let pr = cy.elements().pageRank();

cy.nodes().forEach(n => {
  n.data({
    pr: n.data('label') +';'+ pr.rank(n)
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array and the push method [-> docs <-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
let resultArray = [];

cy.nodes().forEach( node => {
  resultArray.push( //your data function here);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `forEach()` loop you can use the `map()` method to build a new array from an existing one:

```js
let pr = cy.elements().pageRank();
var arr = cy.nodes().map(n => {
  return n.data({
    pr: n.data('label') + ';' + pr.rank(n)
  });
});
```